# How to set Notification on time

Tags: android, time, timer, push-notification, settimeout

Hey Guys, i created the class and now I want to set the `Notification` on time.
For example if someone clicks the button the `Notification` should be shown ten minutes later.

***Code***

```
TextView txtV;
Button bnot;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receiving);
    txtV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtV);
    bnot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bN);
    bnot.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key"); //assign it.
        txtV.setText("Remember :"+value); //set it to textview.
      }
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String value = extras.getString("key"); //assign it.
     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setTicker("Remember")
    .setContentTitle(value)
    .setContentText("Notification content.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start an alarm for 10 minuets from when the button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//1000*60*10 = 10 minutes
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*10, pendingIntent);
```